# Julia - Defining a Linear Programming Problem with MathOptInterface

Tags: optimization, julia, linear-programming

I'd like to write a LP problem in the standard format with MatOptInterface, e.i.:

```
min c'*x
S.t A*x .== b
    x >= 0
```

Now, how can one write this problem with MathOptInterface? I'm having many issues, one of them is how to define the variable "model". For example, if I try to run:

```
x = add_variables(model,3)
```

I first would need to declare this model variable. But I don't know how one is supposed to do this on MathOptInterface.

Comment: what about using JuMP instead?

Comment: I'm using in a package, so I'm looking for the least dependencies possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to implement the LP solver for standard Simplex format:

```
function SolveLP(c,A,b,model::MOI.ModelLike)
    x = MOI.add_variables(model, length(c));
    MOI.set(model, MOI.ObjectiveFunction{MOI.ScalarAffineFunction{Float64}}(),
                MOI.ScalarAffineFunction(MOI.ScalarAffineTerm.(c, x), 0.0))
    MOI.set(model, MOI.ObjectiveSense(), MOI.MIN_SENSE)
    for xi in x
        MOI.add_constraint(model, MOI.SingleVariable(xi), MOI.GreaterThan(0.0))
    end

    for (i,row) in enumerate(eachrow(A))
        row_function = MOI.ScalarAffineFunction(MOI.ScalarAffineTerm.(row, x), 0.0);
        MOI.add_constraint(model, row_function, MOI.EqualTo(b[i]))
    end
    MOI.optimize!(model)
    p = MOI.get(model, MOI.VariablePrimal(), x);
    return p
end
```

For the model, just choose something like `GLPK.Optimizer()`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC in your situation `model` has to be an argument to be specified by the user of your function.
The user can then pass `GLPK.Optimizer()`, `Tulip.Optimizer()` or any other optimizer inheriting from `MathOptInterface.AbstractOptimizer`.
See e.g. [Manual#A complete example](https://jump.dev/MathOptInterface.jl/stable/manual/basic_usage/#A-complete-example:-solving-a-knapsack-problem).

Alternatively you can look at [MOI.Utilities.Model](https://jump.dev/MathOptInterface.jl/stable/apireference/#MathOptInterface.Utilities.Model) but I don't know how to get an optimizer to solve that model.

Comment: Thanks, Felix. I actually got it working and forgot to answer my own question.

Comment: And how did you do it now?

Comment: I've answered the question with the code.